# UndefinedConversionError trying to parse Arabic from email body

Tags: ruby, mongodb, encoding, utf-8, gmail

using `mail` for ruby I am getting this message:

```
mail.rb:22:in `encode': "\xC7" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)
    from mail.rb:22:in `<main>'
```

If I remove encode I get a message ruby

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bson-1.7.0/lib/bson/bson_ruby.rb:63:in `rescue in to_utf8_binary': String not valid utf-8: "<div dir=\"ltr\"><div class=\"gmail_quote\">l<br><br><br><div dir=\"ltr\"><div class=\"gmail_quote\"><br><br><br><div dir=\"ltr\"><div class=\"gmail_quote\"><br><br><br><div dir=\"ltr\"><div dir=\"rtl\">\xC7\xE1\xE4\xD5 \xC8\xC7\xE1\xE1\xDB\xC9 \xC7\xE1\xDA\xD1\xC8\xED\xC9</div></div>\r\n</div><br></div>\r\n</div><br></div>\r\n</div><br></div>" (BSON::InvalidStringEncoding)
```

This is my code:

```
require 'mail'
require 'mongo'

connection = Mongo::Connection.new
db = connection.db("DB")
db = Mongo::Connection.new.db("DB")
newsCollection = db["news"]

Mail.defaults do
  retriever_method :pop3, :address    => "pop.gmail.com",
                          :port       => 995,
                          :user_name  => 'my_username',
                          :password   => '*****',
                          :enable_ssl => true
end
emails = Mail.last
#Checks if email is multipart and decods accordingly. Put to extract UTF8 from body
plain_part = emails.multipart? ? (emails.text_part ? emails.text_part.body.decoded : nil) : emails.body.decoded

html_part = emails.html_part ? emails.html_part.body.decoded : nil

mongoMessage = {"date" => emails.date.to_s , "subject" => emails.subject , "body" => plain_part.encode('UTF-8') }
msgID = newsCollection.insert(mongoMessage) #add the document to the database and returns it's ID
puts msgID
```

For English and Hebrew it works perfectly but it seems gmail is sending arabic with different encoding.  Replacing `UTF-8` with `ASCII-8BIT` gives a similar error.

I get the same result when using `plain_part` for plain email messages. I am handling emails from one specific source so I can put html_part with confidence it's not causing the error. 
To make it extra weird Subject in Arabic is rendered perfectly.
What encoding should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around.

Since only specific emails will be sent to this account to just to use on this application I have full control over formatting. For some reason mail decodes `text/plain` attachment perfectly

so:

```
emails.attachments.each do | attachment |
  if (attachment.content_type.start_with?('text/plain'))
    # extracting txt file
    begin
body = attachment.body.decoded
    rescue Exception => e
      puts "Unable to save data for #{filename} because #{e.message}"
    end
  end
end
mongoMessage = {"date" => emails.date.to_s , "subject" => emails.subject , "body" => body }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `encode` without options, it will raise this error, if you're string pretends to be an encoding but contains characters from another encoding.

try it in this way:

```
plain_part.encode('UTF-8', {:invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => '?'})
```

this replaces invalid and undefined chars for the given encoding with an "?"([more info](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-encode)). If this is not sufficent for your needs, you need to find a way to check if your `plain_part` string is valid.
For example you can use `valid_encoding?`([more info](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-valid_encoding-3F)) for this.

I recently stumbled across a similar problem, where I couldn't be sure what encoding it really is, so I wrote this (maybe a little humble) method. May it helps you, to find a way to fix your problem.

```
def self.encode!(str)
  return nil if str.nil?

  known_encodings = %w(
    UTF-8
    ISO-8859-1
  )

  begin
    str.encode(Encoding.find('UTF-8'))
  rescue Encoding::UndefinedConversionError
    fixed_str = ""
    known_encodings.each do |encoding|
      fixed_str = str
      if fixed_str.force_encoding(encoding).valid_encoding?
        return fixed_str.encode(Encoding.find('UTF-8'))
      end
    end
    return str.encode(Encoding.find('UTF-8'), {:invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => '?'})
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks but no change to output. Still outputs either base64 or MARK-8